# IndexError: list index out of range, but each string can be printed out

Tags: python

I am writing a script to pool lines from fileA when its first two columns are the same as fileB. The fileA is a txt file with three column separated by tab, and fileB is a txt file with two column separated by tab. But it keeps showing error as following:
"site=a[0]+’\t’+a[1]
IndexError: list index out of range"
But I can print a[0], a[1], a[2] and site.

Here is my code:

```
fileB=open('AtoG_mock.txt').readlines()
fileA=open('depth_ice.txt').readlines()
outfile=open('AtoG_depth_ice.txt','w')
dict1={}

for line in fileA:
    a=line.strip().split('\t')
    site = a[0]+' '+a[1]
    if site not in dict1:
        dict1[site]=a[2]

for line in fileB:
    b=line.strip().split('\t')
    site=b[0]+' '+b[1]
    if site in dict1:
        outfile.write(b[0]+'\t'+b[1]+'\t'+dict1[site]+'\n')

outfile.close()
```

I would appreciate any help!

Comment: I don't see any line in your code that matches the one that you claim gives the error.

Comment: Also, what do you get when you just do `print(a)`?

Comment: Sorry, the  error should be:                                                               site=a[0]+’ ’+a[1]
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: I get something like this                                                                                           ['chr1', '1787', '0']                                                                                                  ['chr1', '1788', '0']                                                                                                ....

Answer (score 2):

We can't give you a definitive answer because we don't have access to your data files, but you can easily debug this by wrapping the problematic line in a `try/except` block:

```
try:
    site = a[0]+' '+a[1]
except IndexError:
    print("Error: a is", a)
    raise
```

Most probably there's an empty line somewhere, often the last line.

Comment: It shows:name 'IndexrError' is not defined. When I type IndexError, it does not change color.

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered this sometimes, blank lines for most of time.
You may want to check before parsing.

```
if line == "": pass
```

The other possibility is missing data.

```
if len(a) != 3: print a
```

Comment: You are right, there are lines missing data! I have more than 8000 milline lines, and the last couple milline lines are in different format, not seperated by tabs...  Thank you soon much!